# Full text search using Google Sites API gives 500 internal server error

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-sites

I tried incorporating the full text search using the Google Sites API (via a service account) but to no effect. I also tried it on the Google Oauth playground, but I get 500 Internal server error in both the cases.
I am using https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/domainName/siteName?q=test as the URL.
However, I do get a 200 OK when I fire https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/domainName/siteName (without a query string) in the Google Oauth playground.

Please guide me if I am doing anything wrong.
Thanks

Comment: The site feed can be used to list the Google Sites a user owns or has viewing permissions for (Does the service account have access to it?)

Comment: Yes, the service account has an access to the same. Also, it's not working on Google OAuth Playground. By the way, I am interested in searching in the content feed (as the url suggests)

Comment: I've gotten some lead into this. I am able to search in public sites using the Google Sites API, but not in internal sites. Anyone knows the reason behind this?

Comment: To search internal ones you will need to be authenticated.  Service account will need to have access somehow.   what makes you think the service account has access?

Comment: I meant that the service account is given the access from the Google admin console. This should suffice, right? I am using service accounts for Google Drive API and Directory API as well. It's working fine for them. Hence, I assumed this is how the service accounts are given access. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: that should work, most People assume because they created it in developer console it has access to what they have that's why I asked.

Comment: @DaImTo- What kind of authentication are you talking about for searching in internal sites through API?